# Turn pandas dataframe into numpy values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tree', 1], ['Tree, Hug']], columns=('Tag', 'ticketID'))
```

What I would like to do now I transform the tag category to a numpy array like this

```
df = df[['Tag']]
tags = df.values
```

This however gives me

```
[['Tree']
 ['Tree, Hug']]
```

While I am looking for

```
[['Tree']
 ['Tree', 'Hug']]
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Tree', 1], ['Tree, Hug']], columns=('Tag', 'ticketID'))
>>> [ x.split(', ') for row in df[['Tag']].values for x in row ]
[['Tree'], ['Tree', 'Hug']]
```

Be careful with the `split` call. Have to split `', '` here since original string has a space.

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything in Pandas you can iterate over the `Tag` column with `apply` and convert with `tolist`

```
df.Tag.apply(lambda x: [s.strip() for s in x.split(',')]).tolist()

[['Tree'], ['Tree', 'Hug']]
```